# Water flows under the headwater and soil liquefaction has formed

Tags: geology, water, mountains, groundwater, mountain-building

A retaining wall 40 cm thick with variable height (thin-walled corner) is being built in the mountainous area. At the time of the geotechnical survey and design, there was no reservoir next to the retaining wall. Now, when they began to build, a pond has formed next to the support on one of the sites. The waters now flow downhill towards the wall, and, naturally, under the foundation. Construction has been suspended because the pit is filled with water. That is, the soils will float. I am a young specialist (I am working for the 4th month), but the project was designed by another person. I was tasked with giving an answer in the near future: events with minimal costs. I look on the Internet: clay, resinization, drainage system. Help me to understand. I am attaching an approximate drawing of this site.
Soil - gritty soil of slightly weathered shale with loamy
aggregate up to 30%, with individual sandstone boulders up to 10%. Seismicity - 9 points, freezing depth - 1m. Groundwater up to a depth of 4m is not exposed.

Comment: This is more an engineering question than an earth science question, but even on SE Engineering I don't know that you would get a good answer. The problem would require someone with very good experience in drainage & retaining wall design & construction in difficult situations. To get a good answer, someone would need to examine the site & review all the data.

Comment: By the way, your drawing was not included